# OSX: How to set ACL on a folder

Tags: macos, acl, xattr

How to set ACL to a folder similar to Safari.app?

```
ls -lde /Applications/Safari.app/
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  102 Jun 22 13:25 /Applications/Safari.app/
0: group:everyone deny delete
```

I have tried using :

```
sudo chmod -R +a "group:everyone deny delete" /Applications/xyz
ls -lde xyz
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root  admin  68 Oct 13 16:26 xyz
0: group:everyone deny delete
```

but I am still able to delete the folder xyz.

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one cannot deny `sudo rmdir /Applications/xyz`, nor `sudo mv /Applications/Safari.app /Applications/Safari.app.bak.` **In normal conditions**, root can do whatever it wants.

But the **"System Integrity Protection"** security layer protects Apple's applications when enabled (which is by default: see it with `csrutil status`. For developing reasons I was using `csrutil enable -without fs`). See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) for this SIP explanation.

The **rootless** feature can be seen like this:

```
$ ls -le@d /Applications/Siri.app
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  96 Oct 19  2017 /Applications/Siri.app
    com.apple.rootless   0 
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

So even the root can't remove it under SIP.
OTOH, this did not work under SIP:

```
$ sudo xattr -w com.apple.rootless "" /Applications/xyz
xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Applications/xyz'
```